# Why does OpenCV findEssentialMat return different size for E?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ransac

I'm using the OpenCV findEssentialMat function which uses Nister's five point algorithm to estimate the essential matrix given two vectors of corresponding points. For some reason the matrix E I get changes size. It's either a matrix with 6, 12 or 18 rows. I assume that each 3 rows together is one potential solution for the essential matrix and that I have to use RANSAC to check the distance and find the best inliers, but why does the number of essential matrix's change?

Comment: Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the result is a tuple of the matrix *and a mask*. look closely. perhaps you passed in a varying number of points. the function already applies RANSAC (or something similar).